# Too Many index.php processes with high memory usage

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-usage, high-load

I have wordpress site installed over dedicated server in a separate cpanel account. From couple of days this account experiencing high memory usage, high loadtime and freezing frequently. so I have made certain tests to find the culprit

1. I checked plugin impact through [p3 plugin profiler](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) but impact was normal around 25 %
2. Then I run the top command and sorted the results by Memory. I found many php processes running for this account and consuming memory:

[image]

3. Then I checked which scripts or files these processes are accessing through 'ps -ef | grep career99' command, I found they all were index.php files:
   [image]

How can I debug this, which is causing this issue?

How I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

i'm not certain about this, but first make sure you are reading the memory descriptions correctly. linux will clump similar processes together, but often times this is misread as "linux has ate my memory". see this page for more info: http://www.linuxatemyram.com/

once you are sure this is your bottle neck, you might consider a few things.

how is PHP being executed? are you using mod_php, or are you executing it as a CGI? are you using fast cgi? or a fast cgi daemon?

if you are using mod_fcgid, for example, you might need to configure it to correctly destroy children processes that are no longer in use. or set an upper limit.